# Receive text message with Twilio node module and respond with a text message

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

```
var http = require('http');
var twilio = require('twilio')(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
var qs = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var body = '';
  req.setEncoding('utf8');

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    var data = qs.parse(body);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    // log the received message
    console.log(jsonDataObject.Body);


      twilio.messages.create({
      to:'MY_PHONE_NUMBER',
      from:'TWILIO_NUMBER',
      body:'Hello World'
      }, function(error, message) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('There was an error.')
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      });

      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
      res.end();
  });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('TwiML servin\' server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

> I'm trying to use the Twilio node module to receive a text message and in turn respond to that text message once received. There seems to be no problem receiving the message as I'm able to log the body. But, I get a 401 Authenticate error when I try and respond to that message. I'm using ngrok to expose my localhost so I can hook it into Twilio's API. Please see below:

Where am I going wrong here?

[image: Twilio Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You actually don't need to use the REST API in order to reply to an incoming message to a Twilio number. You can, in fact, respond to the incoming HTTP request with TwiML that describes the message in response.

To do this, you need to use the [`<Message>` verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message). In your application, this would look like:

First, just require the twilio module without the account credentials:

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
```

Then, respond to the incoming request with TwiML, like so:

```
  req.on('end', function() {
    var data = qs.parse(body);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    // log the received message
    console.log(jsonDataObject.Body);

    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    twiml.message("Hello world");

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
  });
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks - but don't I need the credentials for receiving the incoming text? What changes with that part?

Comment: You don't need credentials for receiving, no, you just need to set your URL for your number.

Comment: I've tried my code as it is without the credentials - and the body of the message is no longer logged.

Comment: Something else must have changed then. Aside from being able to create TwiML, the Twilio library is just for making calls to the REST API. You could receive we hooks and respond to them without even installing the package.

Comment: The only thing I did was to remove (ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); from the end of require('twilio')

Comment: I just used the files from this gist to respond to a message to a Twilio number I own. Try this out and see what happens (don't forget, if you restart ngrok you'll need to update the URL for your number). https://gist.github.com/philnash/9c198b1d3bbc5fa0bd30

Comment: Correction - the body does get logged, but the text message does not get sent. Is there anything I need to send the text besides this?

var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
twiml.message("Hello world");

Comment: Have you checked out the gist from my last comment? With that code I was able to respond to my own text message.

Comment: `
// required packages are here

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var body = '';

  req.setEncoding('utf8');

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });

  req.on('end', function() {
    var data = qs.parse(body);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
    var jsonDataObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    console.log(jsonDataObject.Body);

    var twiml = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
    twiml.message("Hello world");

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end();
  });

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
`

Comment: You need to end with:  `res.end(twiml.toString());` otherwise you're still sending back a blank response.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;


var server = app.listen(80, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log(" web app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)


})

app.post('/txt', urlencodedParser,(req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message('Finally Twilio works!');
  res.status(200);
  res.send(twiml.toString());

  });
```

Under your phone number in the console. 
You can click webhooks and change it to the http://"putyourserverhere"/txt
This will automatically text back the inbound user.
Enjoy. Make sure you have the newest version of twilio installed.